# enterprise developer - no signing identities

Tags: ios

I have an app, there is a company that wants to try my app. They have own enterprise account.

They send me a distribution certificate and a provision. I tried to archive my app with their certificate and provision but I took an error as below

[image]

Do I need to be a member of their team? Also they send to me bundle ID , they didn't sent team informations,I just select "none" .

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding they have sent you the certificate but not the matching private key for that certificate (.p12 file). If they are willing to send you the private key as well then you should be able to sign the app (more about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804617/is-it-safe-to-share-the-ios-enterprise-distribution-certificate-with-external-de)).

Another way to do this is by sending them an .xarchive file and asking them to import it into Xcode. Once it is visible in the Organizer they can distribute it with their own certificate (more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035601/how-can-i-deliver-an-ios-app-ipa-to-a-customer-to-be-signed-with-their-own-enter)).

Good luck!

Comment: I can not get .xarchive file because when click product->archive  I get the error . How can I take .xarchive file? Is there any way to get file?

Comment: @user3115233 make sure you are using your own developer certificate not the enterprise certificate when archiving.